# How to set Selenium Python WebDriver default timeout?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, timeout, selenium-webdriver

Trying to find a good way to set a maximum time limit for command execution latency in Selenium Python WebDriver.  Ideally, something like:

```
my_driver = get_my_driver()
my_driver.set_timeout(30) # seconds
my_driver.get('http://www.example.com') # stops / throws exception when time is over 30     seconds
```

would work.  I have found `.implicitly_wait(30)`, but I'm not sure if it results in the desired behavior.

In case it is useful, we are specifically using the WebDriver for Firefox.

**EDIT**

As per @amey's answer, this might be useful:

```
ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
ff.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
myDynamicElement = ff.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")
```

However, it is not clear to me whether the implicit wait applies both to `get` (which is the desired functionality) and to `find_element_by_id`.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I had a look at the source code. It's vague for python binding. But for C#, `ImplicitlyWait` only works for `FindElement/FindElements` (same for Java). Source: [1](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/WebDriver/ITimeouts.cs#48) [2](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5092)

Comment: Thanks.  See my answer below if you're interested.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

In python, the method to create a timeout for a page to load is:

**Firefox, Chromedriver and undetected_chromedriver**:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
```

**Other**:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

This will throw a `TimeoutException` whenever the page load takes more than 30 seconds.

Comment: `set_page_load_timeout` works in chromedriver 75 for me

Comment: This fails with Python 3.7.4, selenium 3.141.0, and gecko 0.26.0.

Answer (score 10):

The best way is to set preference:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("http.response.timeout", 5)
fp.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time", 5)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

driver.get("http://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: @ivan_bilan: If you mean an `Exeption`, no, it doesn't return any

Comment: `dom.max_script_run_time` sets a timeout for executing javascript.  It's not a full pageload timeout.

Comment: This fails with Python 3.7.4, selenium 3.141.0, and gecko 0.26.0.

Answer (score 7):

Information about Explicit and Implicit waits can be found [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits-reference).

**UPDATE**

In java I see this, based of [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html) :

```
WebDriver.Timeouts pageLoadTimeout(long time,
                                 java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit)

Sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error. If the timeout is negative, page loads can be indefinite.

Parameters:
    time - The timeout value.
    unit - The unit of time.
```

Not sure of the python equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

My solution was to run an asynchronous thread alongside the browser load event, and have it close the browser and re-call the load function if there was a timeout.

```
#Thread
def f():
    loadStatus = true
    print "f started"
    time.sleep(90)
    print "f finished"
    if loadStatus is true:
        print "timeout"
        browser.close()
        call()

#Function to load
def call():
    try:
        threading.Thread(target=f).start()
        browser.get("http://website.com")
        browser.delete_all_cookies()
        loadStatus = false
    except:
        print "Connection Error"
        browser.close()
        call()
```

Call() is a function which just

Comment: Your recursion is missing a break condition in case the website is offline. If it's intended, use an infinite loop with a `break` on success.

Comment: Nice universal solution without touching selenium stuff.