# Selenium webdriver with python- how to reload page if loading takes too long?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, timeout, webdriver

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()               #opens firefox
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")      #loads google
```

If it takes too long to load google, how do I make it close the browser and start the code from the beginning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set page load timeout via [`set_page_load_timeout()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=set_page_load_timeout#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout) and catch `TimeoutException`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
while True:
    try:
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    except TimeoutException:
        print "Timeout, retrying..."
        continue
    else:
        break
```

See also: [How to set Selenium Python WebDriver default timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533024/how-to-set-selenium-python-webdriver-default-timeout)

Comment: chrome don't show reload :( , it does reload in background

Comment: I cannot get this to work with geckodriver 0.22 and Firefox 62.  I get the error 'selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: unknown field `sessionId`, expected one of `implicit`, `pageLoad`, `script` at line 1 column 31'

Comment: @skunkwerk, have you ever found out what that message was about, or how to make gecko and ff to work?

Comment: @chris, nope - i ended up using puppeteer instead of selenium/webdriver.