# Python webdriver has no attribute 'manage'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pageload

I want to do next step without waiting for page to load. I tried

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("webdriver.load.strategy","unstable")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
browser.get(url)
```

But I get AttributeError. How can I deal with it? Thanks. I use 3.3.1 selenium package.

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'manage'
```

I have an error running.

```
browser.set_page_load_timeout(30)
```

This is nothing after Message:. I can't identify the type of error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Selenium Python WebDriver default timeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533024/how-to-set-selenium-python-webdriver-default-timeout)

Comment: You're following the Java docs for a Python driver... see the dupe target

Answer (score 0):

I degrade my selenium version from 3.3.1 to 3.3.0. I can use set_page_load_timeout() now.