# setTimeout does not work in python Selenium execute script

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

HI I was trying to pause the execution of Selenium for seconds to wait for Modal popup to show. 
But `time.sleep(5)` didn't work using phantomJS (I've heard that PhantomJS do not support sleep).
 So I came up setTimeout.

```
driver.execute_script('setTimeout(function(){"scroll(0, 300);"}, 3600);')
```

But It doesn't work even in the Chrome Selenium driver.

Even though `driver.execute_script('scroll(0, 300);')` works, I don't know how to execute setTimeout in the selenium.

Comment: please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533024/how-to-set-selenium-python-webdriver-default-timeout

Comment: why not just `import time` and set `time.sleep(3.6)` before `driver.execute_script('scroll(0, 300);')`?

Comment: @Andersson I've tried it. But I can't use time.sleep(3.6). I need to wait for madal popup to show. When I use _time.sleep(3)_, It raises '**Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated**' error. When I got screen shot, modal popup do not show up.

Comment: @VivekMaru I already tried   `driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)` , 
`driver.set_script_timeout(3)` and `driver.implicitly_wait(10)'. But It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to meet some specific condition, you might use [`ExplicitWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) + [`ExpectedConditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html), like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "Specify css selector for your modal div")))
driver.execute_script('scroll(0, 300);')
```

**You can use any selector you like as `By.XPATH`, `By.ID`, etc*

This code should allow you to wait (up to 10 seconds) until visibility of required element before executing script

Comment: I've tried the way you mentioned. But when I got screenshot, modal div didn't come out.
`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"teacher_booked_modal\"]/div/div/div")))`