# Setting timeout on Robot Framework to wait infinity

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am writing a test-cases over a Data-Warehouse software project.
So, some of the tasks are requiring pretty much long time, and sometimes it also depends on servers' responsibility.
My question is
How to set up selenium timeout on robot framework to wait infinitely, or set on max value.

How to avoid this error?

TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)

I have suite setup      set selenium timeout           4 hours
and also 
TestCases 
[Timeout] 4 hours
But for about 10 minutes it gives the error above.

Comment: This link will help you to  address your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533024/how-to-set-selenium-python-webdriver-default-timeout

Comment: That's for selenium only. I need a solution for robot.

Comment: What you mean by Robot?

Comment: @PetarRistevski  show your code trials and errors

Comment: TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)

Comment: @Dev I edited my question description. See it.

Comment: With ultra-long timeouts, sometimes other layers time out, such as the network driver libraries.