# Selenium Chrome (Python): Browser freezes - timeout and quit browser in this case

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use Selenium Chrome to extract information from online sources. Baically, I loop over a list of URLs (stored in `mylinks`) and load the webpages in the browser as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("window-size=1200,800")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.implicitly_wait(30)

for x in mylinks:
    try:
        browser.get(x)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
        city = soup.find("div", {"class": "city"}).text
    except:
        continue
```

**My problem is, that the browser "freezes" at some point.** I know that this problem is caused by the webpage. As a consequence, my routine stops since the browser does not work any more. Also `browser.implicitly_wait(30)` does not help here. Neither explicit or implicit wait solves the problem.

I want to "timeout" the problem, meaning that I want to `quit()` the browser after `x` seconds (in case the browser freezes) and restart it.

I know that I could use a `subprocess` with `timeout` like:

```
def startprocess(filepath, waitingtime):
    p = subprocess.Popen("C://mypath//" + filepath)
    try:
        p.wait(waitingtime)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        p.kill()
```

However, for my task this solution would be second-best.

**Question:** is there an alternative way to timeout the `browser.get(x)` step in the loop above (in case the browser freezes) and to continue to the next step?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Selenium Python WebDriver default timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533024/how-to-set-selenium-python-webdriver-default-timeout)

Comment: I have an implicit wait statement in my code. Also explicit wait does not work, so not exactly a dublicate.