# Selenium driver.requests.Timeout does not stop the request after load timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

How do i set Selenium page load timeout for requests extended library
i have tried 
`from seleniumrequests import Firefox()
driver = Firefox()
driver.request("GET",URL,page_load_timeout=1)`
but it does not actually works for me.

Comment: Possible solutions of your question may be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533024/how-to-set-selenium-python-webdriver-default-timeout

Comment: thanks but the seleniumrequests is a request library with management of cookies and session and its completely differentiate of the normal selenium library.