# How do i try a piece of code for a certain amount of time, and do something else if it doesn't run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"C:\\Users\\MyName\\PycharmProjects\\Project\\chromedriver"r".exe") browser.get("https://google.com/")
```

I am using selenium and this is the code that is supposed to open [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) . I have it in a `while loop` and sometimes (seemingly randomly) it doesn't run. It doesn't throw an error or anything. I was wondering if there is some code similar to `try` `except` (or a proper solution to stop the above from happening) but time based. I want to execute the code then `break` if it doesn't do anything. I tried googling a solution but i didn't find anything helpful

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17536547/12479639

Comment: @Axe319 this fixed the issue. Thanks