# how to solve timeout exception selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

i have the following code used to fill cvv input under an iframe sandbox

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/main/section[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/iframe")))
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div/input"))).send_keys("42342342")
```

the code of iframe is the following

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" class="credit-card-iframe-cvv mt1 u-full-width" src="https://paymentcc.nike.com/services/cvv?id=f2c34789-05ee-4d38-a4cb-5e51dfbe9d6e&amp;ctx=checkout&amp;language=undefined&amp;maskerEnabled=true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" title="Credit Card CVV Form"></iframe>
```

but i got this error

```
File "/home/teflon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

why??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Selenium Python WebDriver default timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533024/how-to-set-selenium-python-webdriver-default-timeout)