# Python & Selenium - Find element by label text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Im trying to locate and click an element (checkbox) from a big selection of checkboxes on a html site using python and selenium webdriver. HTML code looks like this:

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alBU2.png)

```
        <div class="checkbox-inline col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 m-l-sm rightCheckBox">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="i-checks" name="PanelsContainer:tabsContentView:5:listTabs:rights-group-container:right-type-view:2:right-view:2:affected-right" disabled="disabled" id="id199"> <label>Delete group</label>
        </div>
```

My problem is that the only unique identifier is:

```
<label>Delete group</label>
```

All other elements/id's/names are used by other checkboxes or changes from page to page.
I have tried the following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Delete group')]").click()
```

But I only get error when using this.
Error: element not interactable

Anyone able to help with this?

Comment: Please post the complete HTML code instead of screenshot.How could we verify xpath we have created?Whether we want to re-type the HTML code by referring to screenshot?

Comment: refer to updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the below xpath

```
//label[contains(text(), 'Delete group')]//ancestor::div//input
```

Comment: Still getting error: Message: element not interactable
code: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Delete group')]//ancestor::div//input")

Comment: Set [implicit](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implicit-waits-in-selenium-python/) wait before launching the URL

Comment: Still getting: element not interactable.
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @andhaa if you can give me the website url

Comment: Im sorry I cant, since its on an internal network. I can give you more outputs/html code if that helps

Comment: @andhaa try by  giving [pageload timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533024/how-to-set-selenium-python-webdriver-default-timeout).

Comment: Try with `//label[contains(text(), 'Delete group')]//ancestor::div[1]` and then `click`. The message clearly says that the element does exist but it's not intractable, so you can try 
 webdriver wait until clickable or use Javascript clicking on `div` does not help.

Comment: @supputuri when I try your way I get a different error:
move_to requires a WebElement

MohamedSulaimaanSheriff Seems waiting doesnt help with anything. Its allmost like its not clickable at all but it is a checkbox for sure. 

Pasted HTML code vs print screen, could there be anything missing or something?

Comment: @andhaa Man,there is `disabled="disabled"` attribute try by removing this

Comment: @MohamedSulaimaanSheriff Its strange that its there when I copied html code from inspect, because its not there when I view elements while browsing. Its not in the screen shot either. So dont think its really there.

Comment: @andhaa I can help you only if the website is accessible by me

Comment: `move_to` require a webElement - how are you trying to click?

Comment: @supputuri I tried the following:
//label[contains(text(), 'Delete group')]//ancestor::div[1]").click()   And;
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element ).click(element ).perform()

Answer (score 0):

Try with Javascript.

```
checkBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='Delete group']//ancestor::div//input")
# Scroll to checkbox if its not in screen
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", checkBox)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkBox)
```

Note : As per HTML shared by you, checkbox is in Disabled state, so i am not sure click will trigger any action. However above code will click your checkbox.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your code. But didnt work. Found what I belive is the issue tho. Theres more then one "Delete group" label in the whole HTML code. The one Im trying to check is the second one, but my current code obviously tries to check the first one thats disabled. Need to find a way to tell the code to check the second "Delete group" label and not the first.

Comment: Yes in that case you need to share HTML DOM for checkbox you want to click. Also just in case if all of property are similar to HTML you have shared, then you can simply index (if no other difference) is there. Something like **checkBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//label[text()='Delete group'])[2]//ancestor::div//input")**