# Selenium getting stuck when looping through pages

Tags: python, selenium

I have written code that pulls text from sites and analyses them for readability. However, I sometimes get stuck on sites. Is there any way for me to have my program skip to the next iteration of the for loop if it takes longer than x amount of seconds? If there are any questions or clarifications just let me know in comments

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import reqto as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from SpacySylGetter import *
# import readability
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

TextIn = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Max von Klemperer\\Desktop\\KeywordLinks\\Aus2.xlsx')

# print(TextIn)
WebURLs = list(TextIn["URL"].values)
Region = list(TextIn["Region"].values)
Keywords = list(TextIn["Keyword"].values)
Rankings = list(TextIn["Ranking"].values)
spaces = 0
syls = 0
counter = 0
characters = 0
sentences = 0
CLIs = []
FL = []
FLAuto = []
WebTexts = []
goodurl = []
goodKW = []
goodRegion = []
goodRanking = []
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Max von Klemperer\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe')

for i in WebURLs:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        url = i
        driver.get(url)
        el = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
        initText = el.text

        TextPros = ''.join(
            filter(lambda x: x in '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPGQRSTUVWXYZ-.?! \n', initText))
        cleanedStr = ' '.join(TextPros.split())
        print(i)
        textToProc = cleanedStr[600:len(cleanedStr) - 600]
        textToProc.replace("...", ".")
        textToProc.replace("-", " ")
        textToProc.replace(".com", " ")
        if 1000 < len(textToProc) < 100000:
            print(textToProc)
            WebTexts.append(textToProc)
            goodurl.append(i)
            goodRegion.append(Region[counter])
            goodKW.append(Keywords[counter])
            goodRanking.append(Rankings[counter])
        counter = counter + 1

    except Exception:
        print("Bounced")

for i in WebTexts:
    words = len(i.split())
    commas = i.count(",")
    spaces = i.count(" ")
    Hyphens = i.count("-")
    # syls = sylsGet(i)
    # print(syls)
    characters = len(i) - spaces - sentences
    sentences = i.count(".") + i.count("?") + i.count("!")
    characters = len(i) - spaces - sentences - commas - Hyphens
    CLI = ((5.89 * (characters / words)) - (0.296 * sentences / (words / 100))) - 15.8
    CLIs.append(CLI)
    print(CLI)
    # FLK = 206.835 - (1.015 * words / sentences) - (84.6 * syls / words)
    # print(FLK)
    # FL.append(FLK)

driver.close()
CLIExcel = pd.DataFrame()

toAdd1 = np.array(goodurl)
toAdd2 = np.array(CLIs)
toAdd3 = np.array(goodRegion)
toAdd4 = np.array(goodKW)
toAdd5 = np.array(goodRanking)
# toAdd6 = np.array(FL)

CLIExcel["URL"] = toAdd1
CLIExcel["CLI's"] = toAdd2
CLIExcel["Region"] = toAdd3
CLIExcel["Keyword"] = toAdd4
CLIExcel["Ranking"] = toAdd5
# CLIExcel["Flesch Kinkaid"] = toAdd6

print(CLIExcel)
CLIExcel.to_excel('C:\\Users\\Max von Klemperer\\Desktop\\WorkedCLI.xlsx')
```

Comment: Do you already know where it stucks?

Comment: somewhere in this block  `driver.get(url)
        el = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')`

Comment: You probably need to set a timeout on the *get()*. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533024/how-to-set-selenium-python-webdriver-default-timeout

Comment: Hi, that helps, I just occasionally get a site that almost traps the driver. It loads in time but the driver does not skip over to the next URL. 
I think the timer is going to have to influence the python for loop and not the driver @LancelotduLac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue by reopening the Chrome driver for every 5 sites. It seemed to get stuck if I tried to put to many sites through in one loop. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line `el = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')` with

```
timeout = 10
try:
    el = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))
except TimeoutException:
    continue
```

This will wait for the element to appear for 10 seconds and if it is not found, `continue` will continue from the next url in your for-loop.

You will also need the following imports:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: This works well and I am now using it in my program. However, I still am sometimes getting an issue where the next link isn't loaded. I think this is on the python side and not on the web driver side

Comment: I've got it working, I just have to open the webdriver in every iteration of the loop. I think it may be some anti scrape measures built into selenium.